# byref reference to reference cell's value

Tags: syntax, f#

I stumbled upon such problem. I need a function which will know how many times it was called. It needs to be thread safe so I would like to increase the counter using Interlocked.Increment (no lock as lock in this case takes away all the performance gain related to multi-threading).
Anyway, the problem is syntactic: how can I get reference to value in reference cell (&!counter)?

```
let functionWithSharedCounter = 
    let counter = ref 0
    fun () ->
        // I tried the ones below:
        // let index = Interlocked.Increment(&counter)
        // let index = Interlocked.Increment(&!counter)
        // let index = Interlocked.Increment(&counter.Value)
        printfn "captured value: %d" index

functionWithSharedCounter ()
functionWithSharedCounter ()
functionWithSharedCounter ()
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F# automatically treats values of the `ref` type as `byref` parameters, so you do not need any special syntax:

```
let functionWithSharedCounter = 
    let counter = ref 0
    fun () ->
        let index = Interlocked.Increment(counter)
        printfn "captured value: %d" index
```

You can also take a reference of a mutable field, so you could write the following too:

```
let index = Interlocked.Increment(&counter.contents)
```

This works with the filed `contents`, but not with `counter.Value`, because that is a property.

Comment: That's a shame that I didn't try this one. For some reason, I thought implementation of ref is: type ref<'a> = { mutable Value: 'a }, so I did not even consider "special" behaviour. Thanks!